# Ant script execution fails

Tags: ant, javac

I am trying to run Ant script and getting following error at line:

```
        <javac deprecation="on"
         destdir="${prj.build}"
         debug="${prj.debug}"
         debuglevel="lines,source"
         ***classpathref="compile.classpath">***
         <src path="${prj.src}"/>
```

Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the JDK installed? The JRE alone is not enough for many ant tasks.

If yes, read the error message: do you have an environment variable named `JAVA_HOME`, and does it point to the jdk-directory? (This is used by the `ant` wrapper script to setup the paths right.)

Comment: Yes. I have JAVA_HOME set to JDK.